# How to enable boost asio ssl_mode_release_buffers

Tags: boost, openssl, boost-asio

I am writting a SSL server using boost::asio. I am aiming for around 30k concurrent connections (maybe higher later on). So naturally I would like to make the memory requirements per one SSL connection as low as possible. I have found that I should set SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS. However I haven't found a clear answer on how to enable it using boost::asio.

I am looking for boost::asio equivalent to

```
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "ssl server using boost::asio. ... for around 30k concurent connections". That number may be a bit high. The last I read, nqinx (which is legendary for its performance and small footprint), can only handle about 10,000 or 12,000 SSL connections. There's a lot of subjectivity, of course and I can't find that article to or recall hardware.

Comment: I have found threads where people claim to have that amount of connections. Anyway my supervisor thinks so too.

Comment: OK, good luck. Please report back with results. I'm always interested in those sorts of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS is set in Boost Asio by default in all recent versions of Boost (1.47.0 and newer), as long as you use a recent version of OpenSSL. The SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS option is available since OpenSSL 1.0.0d.

Refer to the following lines in [boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp):

```
#if defined(SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS) 
  ::SSL_set_mode(ssl_, SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS); 
#endif // defined(SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS)
```

It was added almost 3 years ago: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/71706